# Silverlight - how to set trigger to popup

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have a popup with UserControl inside. I need to hide this popup and want to create it by trigger. I try the following code:

```
            <Popup.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Popup.MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="popup"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Popup.IsOpen"
                                             To="False" From="True" Duration="0:0:2">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            </Popup.Triggers>
            <blib:TimeZones></blib:TimeZones>
        </Popup>
```

but it does not work

> Failed to assign to property
>   'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'. [Line: 55 Position: 47]

How to make it correctly?

Comment: Triggers is not found in type Style

Comment: Update the question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers in Silverlight don't work in the same way as WPF triggers do. You need to use the interactivity library. Check out this article: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx